# Generic case class not inferring type of Dataset[Row] in Scala?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a trait Rep:

`trait Rep[T]`

another trait that extends Rep:

`trait WrappedDataframe[T] extends Rep[Dataset[Row]]`

and a case class that extends that:

`case class WrapDataset[T](in: Dataset[Row]) extends WrappedDataframe[T]`

In my main I can try to use this however if I don't specify the type I end up with a
**WrapDataset[Nothing]**

```
val ds: Dataset[Row] = simpleDs()
val wrapped = WrapDataset(ds) // wrapped is of type WrapDataset[Nothing]
```

If I explicitly set the type it solves the issue:

```
val ds: Dataset[Row] = simpleDs()
val wrapped = WrapDataset[Dataset[Row]](ds)
```

Why is this happening? It doesn't occur when I implement a similar application for Seq types. I want this typing to happen implicitly.

Comment: Perhaps, this will help you see the problem. Try changing your declaration to something like `val wrapped = WrapDataSet[Int](ds)`. it will compile too 
So, how do you expect the compiler to guess, `Int` is not what you wanted it to infer? `Nothing` is the only type that includes all possibilities in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you instantiate `WrapDataset(ds)`, there's just no way for the compiler to know the `T` type.

`T` doesn't appear in the case class parameters, thus type inference cannot happen.

---

Maybe you meant to write the following?

```scala
trait WrappedDataframe[T] extends Rep[Dataset[T]]

case class WrapDataset[T](in: Dataset[T]) extends WrappedDataframe[T]
```